# Get table-like alignment without actually using tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

How can I achieve this:

```
<table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="margin-right:5px;">
        <h2 id="optiona" class="option optiona optiona2">a. aa   </h2>
      </td>
      <td style="margin-right:5px;">
        <h2 id="optionb" class="option optionb optionb2">b. a   </h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="margin-left:5px;">
        <h2 id="optionc" class="option optionc optionc2">c. aa   </h2>
      </td>
      <td style="margin-left:5px;">
        <h2 id="optiond" class="option optiond optiond2">d.    </h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using something like this (and CSS):

```
<h2 style="display:inline;" id="optiona" class="option optiona optiona1">a. a   </h2>
<h2 style="display:inline;" id="optionb" class="option optionb optionb1">b. aaa   </h2>
<br />
<h2 style="display:inline;" id="optionc" class="option optionc optionc1">c. aaa   </h2>
<h2 style="display:inline;" id="optiond" class="option optiond optiond1">d. aa   </h2>
```

I am also open to options with **JavaScript and/or jQuery**

P.S. I have zero control over the content and they might be rather lengthy (if tehy're too long, I need them to wrap, but I think that happens automatically) so no fixed widths.
 In a table if that longest cell in a column is say 200px wide, the entire column will be 200px, how would I do this with just html and css? Basically need the for h2 elements to line up like this:

```
a.aaaaa b.a
c.a     d.aaa
```

Comment: use divs and css for your layout, external css hopefully

Comment: I believe googling `align divs table with css` will give you the answer.

Comment: almost all the results were about centering text inside a table using divs. @Ibu How would I do it with DIVs and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `display` properties that imitate tables. Not sure they work on older browsers, though.

http://ecommercedeveloper.com/articles/1941-css-display-table-display-table-row-and-display-table-cell/

http://ajaxian.com/archives/display-table

Compatibility:

http://caniuse.com/css-table

Comment: thanks i just used display:inline-block on two divs and put the h2s in theme. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Always better to use the simpler route if it's possible.